# Loki/Promtail - how to setup own scrape_configs?

Tags: logging, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, grafana-loki

I just installed Loki/Promtail using helm like this:

```
helm repo add grafana https://grafana.github.io/helm-charts
helm repo update

helm upgrade --install loki grafana/loki-stack --create-namespace --namespace loki-stack --set promtail.enabled=true,loki.persistence.enabled=true,loki.persistence.size=30Gi,loki.persistence.storageClassName=longhorn,config.table_manager.retention_deletes_enabled=true
```

Now I want to setup my own scrape_configs to aggregate logs from my own application-pods but I'm not sure how to accomplish this (not so familiar with helm):

```
kubectl describe cm -n loki-stack
```

shows the scrape_configs currently loaded as default, which is actually just the stuff that K8s/docker produces but my applications logs are missing as they are not part of the default config ...

How can I add my own scrape_configs to this helm setup shown above?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [here](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/promtail/values.yaml#L233) you can see the format (from the [repo](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/main/charts)), and you have to set additional `--set promtail.snippets=`, (scraped_config passed like [this](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/promtail/values.yaml#L394)).

Comment: Already solved my issue using sidecar's for my pods

Comment: Could you post it as solution? It might help others who encounter same issue.

Comment: Will do asap, give me some time